# How to Merge Chrome driver service with desired capabilities for headless using xvfb?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, mutablecapabilities

I want to merge `ChromeDriverService` with `chromeOptions` or with `DesiredCapabilities` for running browser in xvfb.

Below is part of code `ChromeDriverService` I previously used without selenium grid.

```
String NodeChromeIncognito = "http://localhost:5558/wd/hub"

         ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
         .usingDriverExecutable(new File("driver_linux/chromedriver"))
         .usingAnyFreePort()
         .withEnvironment(ImmutableMap.of("DISPLAY", ":1")).build();
     chromeDriverService.start();
    // commented because using RemoteWebDriver
    // driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService);
```

and below is part code of RemoteWebDriver which I will merge with `ChromeDriverService`.

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = null;
String NodeChromeIncognito = "http://localhost:5558/wd/hub";
String NodeChrome = "http://localhost:5557/wd/hub";
String NodeFirefox = "http://localhost:5556/wd/hub";

    if (browserName.equals("chrome")) {
        cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        cap.setBrowserName("chrome");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(NodeChrome), cap);
    } else if (browserName.equals("firefox")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "driver_linux/geckodriver");
        cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        cap.setCapability("marionette", true);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(NodeFirefox), cap);
    }else if (browserName.equals("chromeIncognito")) {
        ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
        option.addArguments("--incognito");

        cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, option);
        cap.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
        cap.setBrowserName("chrome incognito");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(NodeChromeIncognito), cap);
    }
```

I know I could use `addArguments("--headless")` for chrome, but it does not work well with the my webApp. And also I used `DesiredCapabilities.merge` and error.

How to merge code/configuration `ChromeDriverService` with `ChromeOptions` or `DesiredCapabilites` ?

Comment: Hey@Mysound Magic welcome to stack overflow please keep in mind question posting should be in proper format and easily understandable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mentioned you want to merge **`ChromeDriverService`** with **`ChromeOptions`** or with **`DesiredCapabilities`** both can be achieved. But as of current **`Selenium Java Client`** releases the following **Constructors** are **Deprecated** :

```
ChromeDriver(Capabilities capabilities)
//and
ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService service, Capabilities capabilities)
```

Hence we have to use either of the following options :

- **Option A : Use only `ChromeOptions`** :

  ```
  private static ChromeDriverService service;
  private WebDriver driver;
  //code block
  service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
   .usingDriverExecutable(new File("path/to/my/chromedriver.exe"))
   .usingAnyFreePort()
   .build();
  chromeDriverService.start();

  ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
  option.addArguments("--incognito");
  driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), options);
  ```
- **Option B : Use `DesiredCapabilities` and then use `merge()` from [`MutableCapabilities`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) to merge within `ChromeOptions`** :

  ```
  private static ChromeDriverService service;
  private WebDriver driver;
  //code block
  service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
   .usingDriverExecutable(new File("path/to/my/chromedriver.exe"))
   .usingAnyFreePort()
   .build();
  chromeDriverService.start();        
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
  capabilities.setCapability("...", true);
  ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
  option.addArguments("--incognito");
  option.merge(capabilities);
  driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), options);
  ```

Comment: thank you so much for your answe. I have try your code, it's work for running browser in xvfb, but not work with the selenium grid. i think because of driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), options) url not go to node. because in my code i use NodeChromeIncognito. which is url of node. String NodeChromeIncognito = "http://localhost:5558/wd/hub"

Comment: @DebanjanB option.merge show me an error The Method Merge(DesiredCapabilities ) is undefined for type of chromeOptions