# Python/Selenium - Clear the cache and cookies in my chrome webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to clear the cache and cookies in my chrome browser (webdriver from selenium) but I can't find any solutions for specifically the chrome driver. How do I clear the cache and cookies in Python? Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529761/python-selenium-clearing-cache-and-cookies):

For cookies, you can use the `delete_all_cookies` function:

```
driver.delete_all_cookies()
```

For cache, there isn't a direct way to do this through Selenium. If you are trying to make sure everything is cleared at the beginning of starting a Chrome driver, or when you are done, then you don't need to do anything. Every time you initialize a webdriver, it is a brand new instance with no cache, cookies, or history. Every time you terminate the driver, all these are cleared.

Comment: It is possible to clear cache using this post's answer further down that suggests using sendkeys https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614217/selenium-clear-chrome-cache

Answer (score 9):

**Cache clearing for Chromedriver with Selenium in November 2020:**

Use this function which opens a new tab, choses to delete everything, confirms and goes back to previously active tab.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome("path/to/chromedriver.exe")

def delete_cache():
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData') # for old chromedriver versions use cleardriverData
    time.sleep(2)
    actions = ActionChains(driver) 
    actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 3 + Keys.DOWN * 3) # send right combination
    actions.perform()
    time.sleep(2)
    actions = ActionChains(driver) 
    actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 4 + Keys.ENTER) # confirm
    actions.perform()
    time.sleep(5) # wait some time to finish
    driver.close() # close this tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) # switch back
delete_cache()
```

UPDATE 01/2021: Apparently the settings section in chromedriver is subject to change. The old version was `chrome://settings/cleardriverData`. In any doubt, go to `chrome://settings/`, click on the browser data/cache clearing section and copy the new term.

Comment: `chrome://settings/cleardriverData` just lands on `chrome://settings` for me.

Comment: Might be renamed. Can't test right now, but does `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` work? Otherwise just go to 'chrome://settings` and click on the respective section. Check the URL and change `cleardriverData` to the new section name.

Answer (score 6):

## 2022 Method That Works

I used a similar method to [@do-me's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64806395/10415970) but made it a bit more functional. Also, his <kbd>Tab</kbd>s weren't mapping to the right places for me so I made some edits for it to work in 2022 (on mine at least).

```py
import time
from pathlib import Path

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

CHROMEDRIVER = Path('chromedriver.exe')


def start_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=str(CHROMEDRIVER))
    delete_cache(driver)
    return driver


def delete_cache(driver):
    driver.execute_script("window.open('')")  # Create a separate tab than the main one
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])  # Switch window to the second tab
    driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')  # Open your chrome settings.
    perform_actions(driver, Keys.TAB * 2 + Keys.DOWN * 4 + Keys.TAB * 5 + Keys.ENTER)  # Tab to the time select and key down to say "All Time" then go to the Confirm button and press Enter
    driver.close()  # Close that window
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])  # Switch Selenium controls to the original tab to continue normal functionality.


def perform_actions(driver, keys):
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.send_keys(keys)
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Performing Actions!')
    actions.perform()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = start_driver()
```

Comment: It's working in DEC 22, 2022

Comment: It's still working in FEB 16, 2023

Answer (score 2):

```py
self.driver.execute_cdp_command('Storage.clearDataForOrigin', {
    "origin": '*',
    "storageTypes": 'all',
})
```

Here is a solution from me, it uses the chrome devtools protocol to simulate the "Clear all data" button from the application Tab in devtools. I hope it was helpful

Comment: doesnt work on my linux

Answer (score 1):

None of these worked for me or seemed overly complicated. After some more searching I came across this solution and it works really well and is really simple:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Storage.clearDataForOrigin', {
    "origin": '*',
    "storageTypes": 'all',
})
```

This is clearing all cookies, session storage, local storage, and service workers on that instance of chrome(and maybe some more stuff). Quick, lightweight and simple. I am using python 3.9.12 with Selenium 4.1.5.

Comment: doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

in step one =>

```
pip install keyboard
```

step2 : use it in your code =>

```
from time import sleep
self.driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')
sleep(10)
keyboard.send("Enter")
```

Comment: this is not that simple, the pypi `keyboard` require OS access and it's not trivial in all env and dockers

Answer (score 0):

```
def perform_actions(driver, keys):
    for i in range(0, len(keys)):
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.send_keys(keys[i])
        sleep(.3) #  adjust this if its going to fast\slow
        actions.perform()
    print("Actions performed!")

def delete_cache(driver):
    driver.execute_script("window.open('')")  # Create a separate tab than the main one
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])  # Switch window to the second tab
    driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')  # Open your chrome settings.
    perform_actions(driver,Keys.TAB * 3 + Keys.LEFT + Keys.TAB * 6 + Keys.ENTER + Keys.TAB + Keys.ENTER + Keys.TAB + Keys.ENTER + Keys.TAB + Keys.ENTER + Keys.TAB * 2 + Keys.ENTER)  # Tab to the time select and key down to say "All Time" then go to the Confirm button and press Enter
    driver.close()  # Close that window
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])  # Switch Selenium controls to the original tab to continue normal functionality.
```

edit of @zack-plauché code,
this deletes cache in advanced mode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This solution works as of **2023 September** after chrome was recently updated to 117 version.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
driver = uc.Chrome(driver_executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

def delete_cache(driver):
    driver.execute_script("window.open('')")  # Create a separate tab than the main one
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])  # Switch window to the second tab
    driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')  # Open your chrome settings.
    sleep(3)
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys(Keys.TAB * 6).key_up(Keys.SHIFT)  #select "all time" browsing data
    actions.perform()
    sleep(3)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.DOWN * 5 +  Keys.TAB * 7 + Keys.ENTER)  #click on "clear data" button
    actions.perform()
    sleep(3)
    driver.close()  
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])  
    print("Succesfully cleared the browsing data")

delete_cache(driver)
```