# Python Selenium - How to clear user logged-in session using the same driver instance within the suite

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pytest, ui-automation

**Scenario:**
I need to Test multiple user logins to an application in a single Test file

**Issue:**
When the second user login in the same test class is tried the Automation script fails as the previous users session is not wiped out

**Caveats:**

1. The application does not have a logout feature yet/UI logout process
   has many complications
2. I have put the webdriver Initialization in the conf test and reusing
   the driver instance in all of the tests when the test run is
   performed

**Below is the code structure:**

***Conftest file:***

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def driver_initializer(request):
    webdriver = Webdriver("chrome")
    session = request.node
    for item in session.items:
        classobj = item.getparent(pytest.Class)
        setattr(classobj.obj, "driver", webdriver)
```

***Test Class which uses the driver instance from conftest***

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver_initializer")
class TestClass:
 def test_method(self):
   self.driver.get("url")
```

Comment: Where is the `user login` code block?

Comment: I think deleting the cookies is what he wants.

Comment: ```user  login``` code just does regular login taking the user creds. I am looking for a way to clear user logged in session in the ```TestClass``` that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Probably as when a session is created it stores the the session-id as cookie in the browser.

Now to remove this we need to clear the cookies which are stored in the chrome webdriver. To do this you can do something like this ..

```
def test_some_test_name(self):
  <test code>
  self.driver.delete_all_cookies()
```

and after this you can log in again with new user.

Comment: had tried the `delete_all_cookies` very first, it does not work in this case.

Comment: Did you try clearing cache ??

Comment: you mean clearing cache manually and verifying if it logs out the session ?

Comment: Yes, if it works , then you can do that programmatically too

Comment: yes manually clearing cache works, but programmatically has issues. Tried using `delete_all_cookies`, get all cookies at once and delete 1 by 1 using `delete_cookie` method, Tried to navigate to `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` and performed which didn't work either

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64806395/11724995 , does this help ??

Comment: yes had already tried that post, it didn't work either

Comment: I think if a new driver Instance is used for each test in the suite for the `conftest` and the test code file, this issue can Resolve but I think that will be altogether a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a fixture function indicates the number of times a fixture function is invoked. A pytest fixture with scope as *`session`* is created only once for the entire Selenium test automation session. Session scope is ideal for usage as WebDriver handles are available for the Selenium test automation session.

---

In your usecase, as you intend to test multiple user logins to an application you can't share the *`session`* as the application does not have a logout feature yet. You may opt to drop `scope="session"`

Additionally, once you complete the user login test, you can quit the session using `self.driver.quit()` and also force delete all the cookies.

The resulten files can be:

- Conftest file:

  ```
  @pytest.fixture()
  def driver_initializer(request):
      webdriver = Webdriver("chrome")
      session = request.node
      for item in session.items:
          classobj = item.getparent(pytest.Class)
          setattr(classobj.obj, "driver", webdriver)
  ```
- Test Class which uses the driver instance from conftest:

  ```
  @pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver_initializer")
  class TestClass:
      def test_method(self):
          self.driver.get("url")
          # perform your test
          self.driver.quit()
          self.driver.delete_all_cookies()
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Django? Then you could try something like this:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session  
Session.objects.all().delete()
```

That would delete all the sessions from the database and hence log all users out.